# Using Azure Service Fabric Reliable Actors across different systems

Tags: c#, azure, actor, azure-service-fabric

When using [Service Fabric Reliable Actors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction/), is it possible for an actor client in one system (for example, on a local deployment) to communicate with an actor server in a different system (for example, on an Azure cloud deployment)? If so, how can this be configured? If not, what Azure functionality could I use to achieve this instead? The linked overview gives code examples for the client and server, but not any of the necessary configuration steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Service Fabric client call to an Actor service from a remote machine returns unkown address error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660935/azure-service-fabric-client-call-to-an-actor-service-from-a-remote-machine-retur)

Answer (score 1):

For communicating from a client to an actor running in a cluster, you need to have direct connectivity today - for example the Azure Load Balancer can't be in the way. To configure which cluster to connect to, create a ServicePartitionResolver with the FabricClientSettings, SecurityCredentials, and Endpoints matching the cluster, and then use ServicePartitionResolver.SetDefault (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicefabric.services.client.servicepartitionresolver.aspx)